# Order Status Pending

Tags: magento2, orders, order-status

I have created shipping programmatically in magento2, it created shipment but order status didn't not change

```
if ($_order->canShip()) {
        $this->_helper->debug('creating order shipment');
        $items = [];

        foreach ($_order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
            if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                continue;
            }
            $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
            $items[$orderItem->getId()] = $qtyShipped;
        }
        $shipment = $this->_shipmentFactory->create($_order, $items);
        $data = [
            ShipmentTrackInterface::ENTITY_ID => null,
            ShipmentTrackInterface::ORDER_ID => $shipment->getOrderId(),
            ShipmentTrackInterface::PARENT_ID => $shipment->getId(),
            ShipmentTrackInterface::TRACK_NUMBER => $tracking_no,
            ShipmentTrackInterface::DESCRIPTION => 'abc',
            ShipmentTrackInterface::TITLE => 'abc',
            ShipmentTrackInterface::CARRIER_CODE => 'abc',
        ];
        $track = $this->_trackFactory->create()->addData($data);
        $shipment->addTrack($track);
        $this->_shipmentRepository->save($shipment);

        /* Notify the customer */
        $this->_shipmentNotifier->notify($shipment);
    } else {
        $this->_helper->debug('in else check can ship');
    }
};
```

Comment: please share full code?

Answer (score 0):

Just try required code from below. I think this will definitely work.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface');


//Use this if you have orderId
//$orderId = "100"; //Order Id
//$order = $orderInterface->load($orderId);

$incrementId = "000000165"; //Increment Id
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
        ->loadByAttribute('increment_id', $incrementId);

if ($order->canShip()) {
    // Initialize the order shipment object
    $convertOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
    $shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
        // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
        if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
            continue;
        }
        $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
        // Create shipment item with qty
        $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
        // Add shipment item to shipment
        $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
    }

    // Register shipment
    $shipment->register();
    $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

    try {
        // Save created shipment and order
        $shipment->save();
        $shipment->getOrder()->save();

        // Send email
        //$objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
        //    ->notify($shipment);
        //$shipment->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       echo "Shipment Not Created". $e->getMessage(); exit;
    }

    echo "Shipment Succesfully Generated for order: #".$incrementId;
} else {
    echo "Shipment Not Created Becuase It's already created or something went wrong";
}
```